# Turning off Spring Roo in STS, but still use from command line

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo, spring-tool-suite, aspectj-maven-plugin

From time to time STS seems to bog down or free while working in a Spring Root webapp. It can sometimes be ten or twenty minutes before the UI allows you to really do anything, other than go slow and queue up actions.

We've traced all the the postings/bug reports about "JPA change handler (waiting)" messages and AspectJ issues - but no real permanent solution appears. Sometimes when we upgrade Eclipse or Roo things get better for a while.

We are hoping to figure out if this is really a Roo problem or more of an a Spring/AspectJ issue.

Question: Is it possible to disable Roo in the IDE but still have it build and work OK in the IDE, just not Roo smarts going on?

I thought I just had to remove the "Roo Nature" for the project but that does not seem to completely do it - the Roo Shell keeps popping open when I do a Maven Update.

If not we'll probably look at the push-in refactoring route - but that seem to really be a one-way street.

Our webapp has about 20 domain objects and 30 controllers - it's not tiny but not huge either. We use JPA/Hibernate too.

Thank you - Richard

Comment: a good check would be to capture a few thread dumps (using jps and jstack) while STS is performing so slowly. This might give a hint on what is going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same problem. It seems the JPA Daly support for Eclipse, included in the WTP, generates of a lot of *JPA Event Change* notifications while compiling a project. It seems in projects with aspects, like the Roo ones, this behavior is even worse and makes using the IDE very slow and even hangs sometimes.

As there is not any way to disable it through configuration, you have to remove or move the related files. Ex:

1. Go to the STS/Eclipse installation folder.
2. Run the following command::

   *rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.jpt.* features/org.eclipse.jpt.**

We found also another problem with the Eclipse AspectJ plugin (https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4037) that caused to compile all the project on each modification to any Java class in the project with Aspects applied. It is solved in the recent STS versions, but check it just in case by performing the following steps:

1. Go to the *Project > Properties > AspectJ Compiler* menu.
2. Check the *Other > Outxml* configuration property is disabled.